# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

[image: Google Play Services]

This is React Native project. I have an error after successful build in Android Studio Emulator:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

My files:

**package.json:**

```
...
"react-native": "^0.55.3",
"react-native-camera": "1.1.2",
"react-native-check-box": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.8.1",
"react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
"react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
"react-native-git-upgrade": "^0.2.7",
"react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
"react-native-local-storage": "^1.5.2",
"react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
"react-native-modal": "^5.4.0",
"react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.1",
"react-native-read-more-text": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.27",
"react-native-svg-image": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-text-input-mask": "^0.7.0",
...
```

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
...    
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.anything"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')) {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+'
    compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.+'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
        force = true
        }
    }
    compile project(':react-native-text-input-mask')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')
        ) {
           details.useVersion "27.1.0"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing helped.

Comment: use same version of play-service libraries. Also dont use+ operator in dependencies. found versions `services-base:15.+'`, `vision:12.0.1`

Comment: @alex-khanenya did you find a solution? I have the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Faced the same issue. Then I found out that I missed an important set of instructions to integrate Firebase with Android project: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Here is the summary of the steps in that documentation that helped in my case:

1. Generate `google-services.json` and put it to your `android/app/` directory.
2. Add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` to `buildscript -> dependencies` section of your root-level `build.gradle` config; add `google()` to `allprogects -> repositories` section of the same file.
3. Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'` to `dependencies` section of your app module's `build.gradle` file; add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the very bottom of the same file.
4. Sync and rebuild. Now it should work.

Comment: @alex-khanenya please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

On your `android/app/build.gradle` add one more implementation on dependeces:

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is probably some problem with the dependencies involved.

In my case, making the following changes worked perfectly in the app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
     implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

changed latest firebase-messaging google dependencies and modified other dependencies also in a same version in app gradle file. working fine now

[dependencies version detail you can refer here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I forgot to comment Database Package in MainApplication.java

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
            new AsyncStoragePackage(),
            new RNCameraPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePackage(),
        // add/remove these packages as appropriate
        //new RNFirebaseAdMobPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
        //new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
        // new RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage(),
        // new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(), <==== Comment this package
       // new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
        // new RNFirebaseFunctionsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage(),
       // new RNFirebaseInvitesPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseLinksPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePerformancePackage()
       // new RNFirebaseStoragePackage()
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your are facing this issue in Flutter, Add this dependency in your android/app/build.gradle. And run your main.dart. No need to add any type of controller in ListView. If you are using listview on that page. If you are using Firebase please add this in depencdencies.

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0"`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issues. You have to change the react-native-firebase version in pakage.json file. I found the solution from here

[here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2047)

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me (as for today ***22.09.2023***) was just to remove the .android/ package completely from my project and then run

`npx expo prebuild`

in the root folder and it created a new android folder with a few changes (could see there are some because of GitHub addon in my VSCode), then when I ran the folder in my Android Studio it ran completely fine without any errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Add one more implementation on dependeces in your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    ...
}
```

**Solution 2:**

- Generate `google-services.json` and put it to your `android/app/` directory.
- Add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` to buildscript -> dependencies section of your root-level build.gradle config and add `google()` as first entry to allprogects -> repositories section of the same file.

  ```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            ...
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            ...
        }
    }
  ```
- Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'` to dependencies section of your app module's `build.gradle` file and add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the very bottom of the same file.

  ```
  dependencies {
      ...
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
  } 
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```
- Sync and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is to upgrade all firebase dependencies and don't forget this one below cause Android Studio may not notify you about it.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')`
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE YOUR FIREBASE LIBRARIES!!!!

Eg. if your app uses firebase auth, Google for it, in its documentation they provide with the latest version, paste it to your build.gradle

The libraries added by your Firebase Assistant in Android Studio are usually old.

Answer (score -3):

In the gradle.properties file, try adding::

```
android.enableJetifier = true
android.useAndroidX = true
```